# -1-curves on a nonrational surface.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I would appreciate any guidance to help me prove the claim below.

Let $X$ be a nonrational surface (say a blowup of points on a nonrational minimal model Y), the set of irreducible curves $C$ satisfying $C^2=K_{X} \cdot C = -1$ is always finite.

Comment: Dear SAK,  Have you looked in Hartshorne, Ch. V, where this kind of material is discussed?  Regards,

Comment: From reading Ch. V, I have settled the above. Thanks.